# How to define an SSAS relationship with a "between" key value

Tags: ssas

On an SSAS OLAP cube we have a sales fact table with the details of who (employee) created the sale order and the date order.
The employee is assigned to a department that can change over time.

We would like to use an Employee dimension table with the Initial and End dates of the employee being there.

So something on the line:
Fact_Table: employee_code,sale_date,... (other data)
Employee_Dimension: employee_code, start_date, end_date, department, ...

But cannot figure out how to define the relationship. The equivalent of what would be done in SQL using

```
Select .... 
with fact.employee_code=emp_dim.employee_code and
    fact.sale_date between emp_dim.start_date and emp_dim.end_date
```

Is there any way to do that? Or should we add all the relevant data to the fact table itself?

Comment: Need more info. Is the "DimEmployee" load set up with a Type 2 slowly changing dimension? If not, this may help http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/managing-slowly-changing-dimension-with-slow-changing-transformation-in-ssis.html If so, how do you load your FactSales table? Using Lookups? Then you'll need to use the 'Advanced' tab of the Lookup Transformation in SSIS to deal with start/end dates of your DimEmployee dimension table.

Comment: Lookup Transformation for SCD Type 2: http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2011/01/lookup-slowly-changing-dimension-type.html

Comment: Thks @manderson, will start testing a slowly changing dimension Type 2 for DimEmployee. I don't know what a Lookup Transformation is, we use SSAS to create the cube and cannot find anything similar there, we don't write any query at all, SSAS takes care of all needed relationships we define.

Comment: Lookup Transformation in SSIS. I assumed you were building your Data Warehouse fact tables and dimension using SSIS... then using SSAS to build your cubes off of the data warehouse. How are your facts and dimensions populated now?

Comment: We create our facts and dimensions with an ETL (pentaho), no problem creating the Data Warehouse. Once created we use SSAS to create the cube, and cannot find anything there related to slowly changing dimensions ...

Comment: Sorry. SCD, and Lookup transformations are in SSIS.